# Repo does not have a Release file, cannot apt-get update even after removing apt lists and sources.list

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

In trying to upgrade my Node 10 to Node 12, I'm hitting a problem I'm unable to Google for. No matter the commands I've run, I always get one of two errors that prevents `sudo apt-get update`:

**1)** This appears when running `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`:

```
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                
E: The repository 'https://kong.bintray.com/kong-deb eoan Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

**1.1)** Something I've noticed in the stack trave of `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*`...

```
Err:10 https://kong.bintray.com/kong-deb eoan Release                                       
  404  Not Found [IP: 52.41.180.114 443]
```

**2)** When running `sudo apt-get update`, I'm presented with:

```
pi@pop-os:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security InRelease                                            
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates InRelease                                             
Hit:4 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu eoan InRelease                                                
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports InRelease                                           
Hit:6 http://apt.pop-os.org/proprietary eoan InRelease                                                       
Ign:7 https://kong.bintray.com/kong-deb eoan InRelease                 
Err:8 https://kong.bintray.com/kong-deb eoan Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 54.191.3.105 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://kong.bintray.com/kong-deb eoan Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

What is happening here, and how can I remove Kong and/or fix `sudo apt-get update`?

#### Additional Information:

- I'm running Pop~_OS 19.10, which is directly based off of Ubuntu 19.10
- I do not have PPA, and unfortunately similar questions whose solutions resulted in the `ppa` command do not work for me.

Comment: It seems you are using Pop!_OS. Unfortunately that's off-topic here.

Comment: It's my understanding Pop OS is based directly off of Ubuntu. Pop 19.10 uses Ubuntu 19.10. Are there enough differences to warrant this as off topic? @Kulfy

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Comment: Unfortunately not; I do not have ppa

Comment: @bananabrann Related discussion on meta: [Are Linux Mint (and other unofficial derivatives of Ubuntu) questions on topic?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/684/are-linux-mint-and-other-unofficial-derivatives-of-ubuntu-questions-on-topic)

Comment: Interesting takes on both sides -thanks for sharing. I found this from Ask Ubuntu themselves: https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic. I'll post in Unix and Linux next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've cleared `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory and it did not help, then you need to examine your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. Most probably, your faulty repository is listed there.

Make sure it looks like this:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-updates main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-updates universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-updates multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu eoan partner
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security multiverse
```

You could use the next command to see if your faulty repository is listed there:

```
$ grep kong /etc/apt/sources.list
```

If you need to look for it in a bunch of files, then use the next command:

```
$ grep kong /etc/apt/*
$ grep kong /etc/apt/*/*
```

The second command will look for *kong* in `apt` folder's subdirectories.

Comment: Hey, thanks! I used the first `grep` and got `deb https://kong.bintray.com/kong-deb eoan main`.  I don't want to mess anything up (further, ha), so I'd like to confirm. I can use `sudo rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list` to remove it?

Comment: No, just comment it) Place `#` in front of that string and save.

Comment: Ah, duh. That did it, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome:)

Comment: If you're reading this in the future, I commented that line out as Gryu said then ran `sudo n latest` to allow upgrading to Node v13. Or if you use NVM, you can do `nvm install 13` (or more precise version number)